# How to resolve "InvalidStateError" in React?

Tags: reactjs

I've got this component that is throwing me error that I don't recognize:

import React from 'react';

```
const Search = () => {
  return (
    <section className='section'>
     <div className='container'>

    <div className='row'>
      <div className='columns'>
        <div className='column is-full'>
          <h3 id='branding' className='title is-size-3'>search</h3>
          <form>
            <div className='field'>
              <div className='control has-icons-right'>
              <input type='text' name='search' className='input is-medium' autofocus='autofocus' required />
              <span className='icon is-medium is-right'>
                <i className="fas fa-search fa-2x" />
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
 )
}

export default Search;
```

As soon as I add file uploading input below the text input like this:

```
<div className='field'>
 <div className='control has-icons-right'>
  <input type='text' name='search' className='input is-medium' autofocus='autofocus' required />
  <span className='icon is-medium is-right'>
   <i className="fas fa-search fa-2x" />
  </span>
 </div>
<div className='field'>
  <input type='file' name='file' value='Photo' />
</div>
</div>
```

I get error output from Firefox Dev Edition: `InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`. The Opera browser throws similar error.

Can I get any feedback as to why React throws this error when including input tag for uploading files ?

**screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide where exactly error is coming such as line number or like that , because this error may occur in situation when the object hasn't loaded enough to be able to use

Comment: I added screenshot.

Comment: It's coming from ReactDOM but the error goes away as soon as I remove the file upload input tag. What gives ? Am I doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove value from an input

```
<input type='file' name='file' />
```

here is full example working with files
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-uploading-in-react-js/